# git status shows modified files, but git diff shows nothing

Tags: git

I have done `"git reset --soft HEAD^"` to get rid of some files from commit, but I have some problems.

Command `"git status"` shows list of files (modified -- green). But if I want to shows changes with command `"git diff"` git shows nothing.
Also when I trying revert changes by `"git checkout <FILE>"` it gives no result.

If I open any of these files I see my changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have done "git reset --soft HEAD^" to get rid of some files from commit, but I have some problems.
>   Command "git status" shows list of files (modified -- green).

This expected behavior according to documentation:

> --soft
>
> Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do). This leaves all
>   your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put
>   it.

In future use `--mixed` flag to move files to not-staged area

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^
```

OR just:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

because `--mixed` is used by default

---

The current situation may be fixed by:

```
git reset HEAD -- <file>
```

This will make a file unstaged. Or without `-- <file` to apply to all files.

Or use `git diff --cached` to show diff of staged files.

---

> Also when I trying revert changes by "git checkout " it gives no result.

`git checkout <FILE>` works if file is unstaged.

Comment: Thanks. I do `git reset HEAD^` (without --soft) and all of commands (diff, checkout) works as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --soft` leaves the files as staged, so you need to use `git diff --cached` to show the diff of the staged changes.